# Acces a PouchDB in android/java?

Tags: java, android, cordova, couchdb, pouchdb

I am trying to fetch data from a PouchDB in Java for my Cordova app. I have made a backgroundservice in Java using [this](https://github.com/Red-Folder/bgs-core/wiki/Build-your-own-Background-Service) plugin. I use that for my cordova application to fetch some relevant data from my API. To get this data i need some information of the user, like the ID, which i have stored in my PouchDB in the JavaScript. Now i want to fetch this data in my BackgroundService.

I have tried:

```
    SQLiteDatabase db = openOrCreateDatabase("Survalid",MODE_PRIVATE,null);
```

But i have been unable to find the right documentation of getting data from the database. Also since the SQLiteDatabase object is a class from android, i think it creates a new Database rather then opens the existing pouchdb.

Question in short:
Is it possible to open and fetch data from a PouchDB in Java, if so how?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This could be for you: https://github.com/nolanlawson/PouchDroid/

Comment: Thanks, i will take a look at it. I'm not sure that works with Cordova though.

Comment: PouchDroid is an abandoned project (I wrote it). I wouldn't recommend it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [sqlite plugin 2](https://github.com/nolanlawson/sqlite-plugin-2) and [where is data stored](https://github.com/nolanlawson/cordova-plugin-sqlite-2#where-is-data-stored) which tells you how you can access the data from Java. Note, though, that you probably shouldn't modify this data, although you can read it if you want.

Comment: That helps me out a bit better. Thanks alot.